# how to add summary page in the end of eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

i wrote an eclipse plugin with wizard.
the wizard contain some pages, and I want that when the user press on finish ( in any page) i will be able to open page with summary of all the fields in the other pages and only then preform the finish function 
any I idea how can implement it?

thanks

Comment: Why don't you include the summary page as a last step in the wizard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to do something in the `performFinish` method of the wizard:

```
@Override
public boolean performFinish() {
    IWizardContainer container = getContainer();
    if (summaryPage.equals(container.getCurrentPage())) {
        // Do something.
        return true;
    } else {
        container.showPage(summaryPage);
        return false;
    }
}
```